# How do I find a mapping f : X -> Y to characterize the relationship between 2 time-series X and Y?

Tags: python, time-series, mapping, decomposition

I have a time series Y, and another time series X related to Y.

The value of Y is affected by X and some noise.

How can I separate the effect of X on Y ?

That is, how do I find a mapping f : X -> Y to characterize the relationship between X and Y ?

Here is the figure illustration of X and Y:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edGa0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but the `statsmodels` package `seasonal_decompose` (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) can handle sesonal decomposition.  In short:
if x is an array-like representation of your timeseries (with noise):

```
from statmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompse

decomp = seasonal_decompose(x, model='additive', period=20)
```

`model` can also be `'multiplicative'`, but `'additive'` seems more appopriate for your example... can also experiment with different values for `period`.  To get the trend, seasonal cycling, and noise (residuals) components, use `decomp.trend`, `decomp.seasonal` , `decomp.resid`.  You can also plot all the components together with just `decomp.plot()`. You may need to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` first, then `plt.show()` to get the plot to actually appear.

A full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

n = 140  # no. of observations
x = np.arange(n)
trend = np.linspace(20, 25, n)
seas = 10 * np.sin(x / 3)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=5, size=n)
signal = trend + seas + noise
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()  # if not in a notebook

decomp = seasonal_decompose(signal, period=20)
decomp.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: noisy signal]

[image: decomposition]